Radon-Nikodym derivative of posterior wrt prior
Suppose $X \sim \pi_X$ and the RV $Y$ is obtained from $X$ with some noise. Note that $X$ may have continuous or discrete distribution, and $Y|X$ may have continuous or discrete distribtuion.
Now, I want to consider the derivative of posterior wrt the prior. In particular, the posterior given that $Y \in R \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$. The derivative need not always exist - consider the case where $X$ is continuous and $Y=X$ so $X|Y \in R$ has a point mass (for the case where $R$ is a single element). We shall use the notation $\pi_{X|R}$ to denote the posterior distribution.
For a given $R \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$, suppose you are given that the RN derivative exists, then I want to find the ratio
$$ \frac{\frac{d\pi_{X|R}}{d\pi_{X}}(x)}{\frac{d\pi_{X|R}}{d\pi_{X}}(x')}$$
for $x,x'\ \in \mathcal{X}$.
I am a little lost here. I read this question on Bayes Rule and it seems to me that I can write $\frac{d\pi_{X|R}}{d\pi_{X}}(x) = \frac{P(Y \in R|X=x)}{P(Y \in R)}$. However, this seems problematic since  $P(Y \in R)$ can be zero. For example, consider $X,Y$ to be i.i.d. uniform$[0,1]$ and $R = \{0.5\}$. The RN derivative is clearly $1$ everywhere but this Bayes Rule approach gives a $0/0$ expression.
I could possible work with densities for this case and write $\frac{d\pi_{X|R}}{d\pi_{X}}(x) = \frac{f(Y = r |X=x)}{f(Y = r)}$ when $R = \{r\}$ but this is not convincing to me since I want to treat $R$ as a general set, not necessarily a singleton.
My question is: when the RN derivative exists, can I always write
$$ \frac{\frac{d\pi_{X|R}}{d\pi_{X}}(x)}{\frac{d\pi_{X|R}}{d\pi_{X}}(x')} = \frac{P(Y \in R|X=x)}{P(Y \in R|X=x')}?$$
Do not worry about $P(Y \in R|X=x)$ or $P(Y \in R|X=x')$ being zero here; I can ensure I only consider sets $R$ such that these are non-zero. I am mainly concerned about `cancelling' the $P(Y \in R)$ in the two expressions.
